# Upgrade PySide 1.2.2 to 1.2.4 Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, pyqt4, homebrew, pyside

I have installed Qt4/PySide via brew but PySide and Shiboken versions are 1.2.2. 
`brew upgrade pyside` did not work. It says `cartr/qt4/pyside@1.2 1.2.2 already installed`. Need lates 1.2.4 version.

Comment: Is it a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751249/upgrade-pyside-1-2-2-to-1-2-4-mac-os-sierra ? Do you think you have a better answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install `pip` and, after that, install PySide using pip: `pip install -U PySide`

See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide/1.2.4

Comment: It worked but now I get this error running my script: from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python[version]/site-packages/PySide` did not helped

Comment: Have you installed PyQt4 first? If not, I suggest that install PyQt4 and then reinstall PySide (I have problems in the past because of installed in the reverse order)

Comment: Yes, I have installed PyQt4 first. Re-installing everything solved the problem.